# How to set the path for a non-interactive, non-login process which is not executed in bash

Tags: linux, jenkins, phing

It's jenkins installed as a package, which executes phing, but everything is executed with /bin/sh it seems. So bash_env is not an option I think. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change **Shell executable** under the Manage Jenkins configuration

Comment: Sorry @Slav, i only saw this now. Apparently my notifications aren't set up properly. I will try that early next week and get back to you. Thanks already!